# Analogous theorem for Hilbert modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I have studied modular forms and saw a correspondence like a newform correspond to a  automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A_Q})$. Does any similar result holds for Hilbert modular forms?

Also we know $S_k(\Gamma_1(M))= \bigoplus\nolimits_{\epsilon:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*\to\mathbb{C}^*} S_k(\Gamma_0(M),\epsilon)$ and $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}S_k(\Gamma_1(M))$ ~ $M^2$ where $\Gamma_1(M)$ and $\Gamma_0(M)$ are well-known congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. $S_k(\Gamma_1(M))$ is the subspace of holomorphic cusp forms and $S_k(\Gamma_0(M),\mathbb{\epsilon})$ is the subspace of holomorphic cusp forms having character $\epsilon$. I want to know again if there are similar results for Hilbert modular forms or Hilbert Cusp forms.

If yes, please suggest some good references for this.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice summary of the newform theory of Hilbert modular forms in Section 3 of the paper [Twists of Hilbert Modular Forms](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~malhw/twists.pdf) by Thomas R. Shemanske and Lynne Walling.

As for your decomposition of the space of cusp forms, I mention a generalization of it to Hilbert modular forms towards the end of Section 2 of my paper [Characterizing adelic Hilbert modular cusp forms by coefficient size](http://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/blinowit/papers/hmfcoefficientsize.pdf). There's likely a much friendlier reference for these decompositions, but unfortunately it's been quite a while since I thought about this stuff and don't know of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Another good reference for seeing how Hilbert modular forms relate to automorphic forms/representations is Gelbart's "Automorphic forms on adele groups".

Comment: @LerayJenkins Thanks though it does not talk much about the relation between classical and adelic Hilbert modular forms.